# Google Chrome duplicate and open with multiple profile

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

I'm using Chrome 13.0.782.14 dev-m and have followed the instructions [here](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=179236), copied my `Default` folder to a `test` folder, then used the flag to point to that `test` folder.

I found that below items are not being carried over to new profile:

- saved password
- bookmarks
- extensions
- preference
- auto-suggestion in address bar

Is this the way how Google Chrome intended to be? Is there any way to carry over at least auto-suggestion in address bar, which is a valuable part to duplicate profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to simulate this - saved passwords will not be carried forward, but rest were carried forward. I suggest you enable Chrome sync - it will sync bookmarks, extensions & passwords.

As for address bar suggestions, copying `History` & other `History Index *` files from your current profile to the new one (to the `Default` folder) resulted in the suggestions from my previous profile getting carried over.